# Just started learning about PHP and Apache, localhost displaying entire php code

Tags: php, apache, localhost

When i go to localhost in my browser, I get the "It works!" which is a good side.

However, when I create a new php file (test.php) in the htdocs file such as,

```
<?php  
Echo "Hello, World!"; 
?>
```

And i go to localhost/test.php,

I get the exact same thing.

```
<?php  
Echo "Hello, World!"; 
?>
```

Aren't I supposed to get just Hello, World! ???

I just started learning this today using a YouTube tutorial. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: You will need to install PHP. Download it from www.php.net/downloads.php

Comment: I already installed PHP - it's on my C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are loading the PHP module `php5_module` on your Apache.
Check your `http.conf` file and uncomment or add the following line:

`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

Also verify the http.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. Uncomment or add the following line:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Then restart your Apache server.

Comment: This is the code I have in the http.conf file:
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

Comment: I added that line in, but nothing changed.

Comment: Verify the http.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. Uncomment or add the following line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`